# Read CSV to float array

Tags: python, csv

I need to read this CSV to an array of floats. I'm new to python and unsure how to convert because when I read in the CSV it says that I am using type "Dictreader" hence why I am trying to convert. Thanks!

[Screenshot of where I'm at][1]

```
   import csv
    with open('NP.csv') as csvfile:
        NP = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    with open('A.csv') as csvfule:
        A = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    [r, c] = size(NP);
    [r2, c2] = size(A);

    for i in range(0, r):
        for j in range(0, c):
            NP(i,j) = float(NP(i,j));
    for i in range(0, r2):
        for j in range(0, c2):
            A(i,j) = float(A(i,j));
```

Comment: put your code and your input csv not an image of your code!!!

Comment: Please try doing some research before posting to StackOverflow. Otherwise, pandas `read_csv` might be exactly what you want.

Comment: Could you show a sample (maybe the first 10 lines or something) of `NP.csv` and/or `A.csv`?

Comment: Please add the function `size()` to your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read in a CSV file containing only floating point numbers, you could do this as follows:

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
        return [list(map(float, row)) for row in csv.reader(f_input)]

NP = read_csv('NP.csv')
A = read_csv('A.csv')
```

So if `NP.csv` contained:

```
11.11,22.22,33.33,44.44
55.55,66.66,77.77,88.88
```

`NP` would now contain:

```
[[11.11, 22.22, 33.33, 44.44], [55.55, 66.66, 77.77, 88.88]]
```

Tested in Python 3.x